# nginx 408 connection reset by peer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have an nginx (1.2.0) server running on ubuntu 10.04.
It acts as a reverse proxy for a rails app running on unicorn.

One user has been running into an issue uploading files. The user can upload 95% of the time, but certain files will return a "Connection Reset by Peer". These files reliably return the same 408 error. The error occurs with Firefox (12). The user also has IE installed and that uploads the same file just fine. I can also upload the file just fine (Safari)

The weird thing is that the request never seems to reach the unicorn servers; No trace of the request can be found in unicorn or rails log.

The problem has existed on several nginx installations

- 1.0.5
- 1.0.15
- 1.2.0

Random Facts

- Issue exists on wireless and wired network.
- Issue also existed on other versions of Firefox (11 & 3.6)
- Rails 3.2.3 (also existed on 3.1.3)

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. thank you.

#### from nginx access_log

[error]

> 10.X.X.XX - - [07/May/2012:10:39:59 -0400] "POST /data/jobs/aL2OccMe8r4ylk-hGRWekO/attachments/ HTTP/1.1" 408 0 "http://fake.name.com/pages/jobs/aL2OccMe8r4ylk-hGRWekO/attachments/new/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0"

[success]

> 10.X.X.XX - - [07/May/2012:10:41:53 -0400] "POST /data/jobs/aL2OccMe8r4ylk-hGRWekO/attachments/ HTTP/1.1" 302 146 "http://fake.name.com/pages/jobs/aL2OccMe8r4ylk-hGRWekO/attachments/new/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.5 Safari/534.55.3

Comment: added `client_body_buffer_size 32k;`
and bumped timeouts `keepalive_timeout 15;`
`client_body_timeout 10;`
this seemed to solve my problem